# Prove the Binomial Theorem using induction (What is mathematics book)

Tags: induction, binomial-theorem

I read What is Mathematics book by Richard Courant and Herbert Robbins and there is an exercise where I should prove the Binomial theorem using induction. Here is an expression to be proved:
$$
 C^n_i = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n - i + 1)}{1 * 2 * 3 ... i} = \frac{n!}{i!(n - i)!}
$$

I will be grateful for any help you can provide

Comment: Write $n! = n(n-1)\cdots 2 \cdot 1$ and $(n-i)! = (n-i)(n-i-1) \cdots 2 \cdot 1$ and do some cancellations.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks for a quick response. I'm sorry, but maybe I didn't understand you correctly. I tried to write something like this
$$
\frac{n(n + 1)}{i!(n - i)(n + 1 - i)}
$$
But I'm not sure that I'm thinking in the right way.

Comment: $$\frac{n!}{(n-i)!}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots(n-i)(n-(i+1))\ldots1}{(n-i)(n-(i+1))\ldots1}=n(n-1)\ldots(n-i+1)$$

Comment: @A.Goodier I got it. Thanks a lot :-)